How to Add Social Icons to About Page and/or Footer using FixIt theme?
Am new to Hugo and am trying to place Social Icons (GitHub, LinkedIn & Footer) to a specific page (e.g. About page or Footer).
Using: hugo v0.128.2 and the FixIt 2 theme.
Inside my hugo.toml file (which is located in the root folder), have the appropriate values inside this section:
[params.social]
GitHub = "myGitHubUser"
LinkedIn = "myLinkedInUser"
Twitter = "myTwitterUser"


Have an About page inside
project_folder
|
|-content
   |
   about.md


about.md:
+++
title = 'About'
date = 2024-07-18T00:55:21-07:00
draft = false
menus = ['main']
class = 'center'
+++

About Me

Tried putting social = true inside the +++ slug section but nothing (GitHub, LinkedIn, and Twitter icons) comes up inside the About page? These icons do come up inside my home page (above my posts) when I set this inside hugo.toml:
[params.home]
  [params.home.profile]
  enable = true
  social = true

How can I make them only appear in a specific page that I want (e.g. About page or Footer) Also, how could I position (right, center, or left) them?

The profile icons on the homepage are generated by the two following pages:
/layouts/partials/home/profile.html (lines 57 to 103)

/layouts/partials/plugin/social.html

You need to reuse the code in the home/profile.html page and copy-paste it in the layout corresponding to the page where you want the icons to appear.
For footer, that would probably be in:
/master/layouts/partials/footer.html

About page does not seem to have a specific template, so you may have to create a specific one using a copy of:
/layouts/_default/single.html

